# create regexp for username validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help creating regexp. It's just I don't quite understand how to create a regexp. How do i create a validation for username with some rules like this

1. only Uppercase, lowercase, underscore(_) and dot(.) are allowed
2. start with an underscore(_)

I've already tried some regexp from mozilla developer site, but it doesn't seems right

```js
var usernameRegex = new RegExp(/_+[A-Za-z]/);
var usernameRegexFound = usernameRegex.test(username.value);
if (!usernameRegexFound) {
  msg = "Invalid Username";
}
```

I expect some username like so

_username = true

_username1 = false

.username = false

username = false

and also are there any sites for me to understand how to create regexp, because I got some more thing to do with it

```js
function validuser(username) {
  var msg = "valid";
  var usernameRegex = new RegExp(/_+[A-Za-z]/);
  var usernameRegexFound = usernameRegex.test(username);
  if (!usernameRegexFound) {
    msg = "Invalid Username";
  }
  return msg;
}

console.log(validuser("_username","Valid?"));
console.log(validuser("_username1","Invalid?"));
console.log(validuser(".username","Invalid?"));
console.log(validuser("username","Invalid?"));
```

Comment: `^_[a-zA-Z_.]*$` should be sufficient.

Comment: Technically `_[\w.]*`

Comment: I made you a snippet. It always helps to post a [mcve]

Comment: That's work! thanks, btw can you explain what is \b used for? I just doesn't quite understand with the flags

Comment: @Virtualanang `A-Ba-b` matches only letters: `ABab`, google "js regex" and get familiar with symbols

Comment: @Virtualanang: `\b` is used for word boundaries, although since you want to match it with full string, using `^` start anchor and `$` end anchor is better. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aLYdBK/1) Also, as I know in general `_` is a perfectly valid identifier, hence I have used `*` quantifier with character set, meaning none of the characters from character set is mandatory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When creating regex, you can help yourself using https://regex101.com/.

That said, here is your regex :

```js
function test(username) {
  const regex = new RegExp('^_{1}[A-Za-z\.]*$', 'i');

  // Alternative version considering @thomas points
  // const regex = new RegExp('^_[A-Za-z._]+$', 'i');
  
  return regex.test(username);
}

console.log(test('test'));
console.log(test('_test'));
console.log(test('_te.s.t'));
console.log(test('_teST'));
console.log(test('Test_'));
console.log(test('^zdq^dz.'));
console.log(test('_teS/T'));
console.log(test('_9901A'));
```

[image]

Comment: underscore does not seem optional as per examples

Comment: still wrong actually on multiple points: `1)` {1} is never needed, `2)` \. (backslash) is not needed `3)` your group does not allow underscore in the name part as specified in the question `4)` * quantifier makes the entire name after underscore optional

Comment: I've added a answer fitting your requirements. My answer being accepted I though it was ok. Thank you for your inputs.